# HTTP request 'Host' header not resolved on server

Tags: http

When i send this request:

```
GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

The connection just times out. When looking into the server log, this is what i found:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2016:07:58:01 +0100] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 408 321 "-" "-"
```

Any ideas why it does that?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your server setup this is extremly hard to answer.

Comment: And I have no idea about the title of your question. Is this about a 408 status code or about a request header? Or what exactly is your problem.

Comment: When is send this request the server doesn't resolve the 'Host' header. It resolves any other header. And after 5 minutes it returns 408. The server is XAMPP with deafult settings.